# Regex doesn't work in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have some expected pattern for data that I receive in my server. The following 2 lines are expected as I wish.

```
¬14AAAA3170008@¶

%AAAA3170010082¶
```

So, to check if the data it's fine, I wrote the following regex:

```
(?<pacote>\\A¬\\d{2}[a-fA-F0-9]{4}\\d{7}.{2})
(?<pacote>\\A[$%][a-fA-F0-9]{4}\\d{10}.)
```

And it works fine in regex101.com but Java Pattern and Matcher doesn't understand this regex as expected. Here goes my Java code

```
String data= "¬14AAAA3170008@¶%AAAA3170010082¶";
Pattern patternData = Pattern.compile( "(?<pacote>\\A¬\\d{2}[a-fA-F0-9]{4}\\d{7}.{2})", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE  );
Matcher matcherData = patternData.matcher( data );


if( matcherData .matches() ){
  System.out.println( "KNOW. DATA[" + matcherData .group( "pacote" ) + "]");

}else{
  System.out.println( "UNKNOW" );

}
```

And it didn't worked as expected. Could someone help me figure what mistake I'm doing?

Comment: "And it didn't worked as expected." In what way? Did it not match? Did it match but with the wrong groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Matcher#matches`, which matches the whole input.

However, the `Pattern` you're using only applies for the first input, and your whole input contains the two cases concatenated.

On top of that, the `\\A` boundary matcher implies the pattern follows the start of the input.

You can use the following pattern to generalize and match the two:

```
String test = "¬14AAAA3170008@¶%AAAA3170010082¶";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
//   | named group definition
//   |         | actual pattern
//   |         | | ¬ + 2 digits or $%
//   |         | |            | 4 hex alnums
//   |         | |            |              | 7 to 10 digits
//   |         | |            |              |        | any 1 or 2 characters    
//   |         | |            |              |        |      | multiple times (2 here)
    "(?<pacote>((¬\\d{2}|[$%])[a-fA-F0-9]{4}\\d{7,10}.{1,2})+)"
);
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group("pacote"));
}
```

**Output**

```
¬14AAAA3170008@¶%AAAA3170010082¶
```

Comment: @mbomb007 looks like you're right, will amend the comment, thanks.